# Tried to connect a device to web via webusb but.. Failed to claim interface: Access denied (insufficient permissions)

Tags: google-chrome, webusb

I am using the webusb API in Google Chrome to try to connect a device to the browser. It worked with webserial API, but I am having trouble getting it to work with webusb API.

1. I am using HTTPS (Github pages)
2. I enabled `#new-usb-backend` for my browser
3. I can open the device and select configuration, but device.claimInterface(0) is not working (and I can confirm that 0 is an interface number).
4. None of the two interfaces this device has seems to be claimed

The error I get looking at `chrome://device-log` is
`Failed to claim interface: Access denied (insufficient permissions)`

I'm not sure where to go from here. I would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

device.claimInterface(1) worked. I heard somewhere mac automatically claims interfaces. Perhaps the first interface was claimed, although the api indicated otherwise. Anyhow, something about the second interface worked that didn't work in the first.

Answer (score 0):

That error message indicates that there is either an existing driver that has claimed the interface or (Windows only) the WinUSB driver hasn't attached to the interface in order to enable applications like your browser to claim it. On Windows you can use the Zadig tool to force Windows to change the drivers being used for a USB device.

If the device can be opened using the Web Serial API then that indicates that the operating system has already loaded a serial driver for the device and so it has claimed at least some of the device's interfaces.

Why, if the Web Serial API works to connect to your device, are you trying to connect to it with the WebUSB API instead? Are you now on a different operating system which doesn't provide a USB serial driver compatible with the device?

Answer (score 0):

if you had installed adb, run `adb kill-server` in terminal maybe effect.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I get this error when I kept open another software that is claiming all the interfaces, like **balenaEtcher** .
Stopping these softwares usually solves the problem.